# Norms of integral ideals representing an integer

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field. Given an unramified prime $p \in \mathbb{Z}$ and integer $\alpha \geq 1$ denote by $R(p^{\alpha})$ the set of ideal classes (in the class group) occupied by integral ideals of $K$ with norm $p^{\alpha}$.

**Question 1.** Am I correct in my understanding that $R(p)$ consists of only one ideal class where-as $R(p^{\alpha})$ with $\alpha > 1$ can consist of several ideal classes?

**Question 2.** Am I correct in my understanding that if $p$ is *ramified* then even $R(p)$ can consist of several ideal classes?

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know? Where are theses questions from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to question 1 is "no", $R(p)$ can consist of more than one ideal class.

For example, take $K = \Bbb Q(\sqrt {-23})$ and $p = 3$. Then there are two ideals with norm $p$: $(3, \frac{1 + \sqrt{-23}}2)$ and $(3, \frac{1 - \sqrt{-23}}2)$. They are not in the same ideal class.

This makes the statement of question 2 not so meaningful - it is true, nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful! I was also wondering about the following : If in the factorization $(p) = \prod \mathfrak{p}$ I know the norm of each $\mathfrak{p}$ and the ideal class to which they belong, does this determine $R(p)$ ?

Comment: Of course, every ideal having norm $p$ must appear in the factorization of $(p)$ (although the converse is not true).

Comment: Thanks a lot, this clarified a lot of confusion.